# How to get the password and email form boxes to look the same in razor

Tags: html, model-view-controller, razor

In [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lx5SV.jpg) you can see that on my webpage the password editor box looks different compared to the Email text editor box. I looked at examples of having the same box used for both a password and text editor box and found [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-controls). Showing that by both of them having the `form-control` class they look the same. However my cshtml code also has both my editors using the `form-control` class, shown below

```
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"} })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>
```

How do I edit my Password box to make it look the same as my Email box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is causing this problem but it is one that i have seen before. One of the things you could do to fix this is using the `@Html.EditorFor` for the password and extending your htmlAttributes from `new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }` to `new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "password" } }`.

This would be your code

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "password" } })
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this provides clarity.